# Storing default instances of an NSManagedObject in every new file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have a core data document based application.  Part of my model works by having a DeviceType table, and a Devices table with a relation between them.  I would like my application to be able to store the list of DeviceTypes separately from each file, and possibly be able to sync that to a server later.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Gabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a lot of database terminology with Core Data. You should break that habit as soon as possible (the reasons why are given in the introductory paragraphs to the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)).

I assume your "usually-static" device list is something you want to be able to update as new devices come out? I would actually recommend just storing the list as a PLIST resource in your app bundle and pushing an update to the app when new devices come out (for simplicity). Using a dictionary-based PLIST, your keys can be device IDs and that key can be a simple string attribute of your managed objects. It's perfectly reasonable to look things up outside your Core Data model based on some ID.

If you *must* update, I'd still include the "default" list with the app (see above) but if a ".devicelist" (or whatever) file is present in the documents folder, use that instead. That way you can periodically check for an updated list and download it to the docs folder if it differs.

If I've misunderstood you, I encourage you to clarify either by editing your question or posting comments.

Comment: That is very helpful.  I know that I'm probably using too much database terminology, I have used MySQL, SQLite for years and this is my first real leap into Core Data.  I suppose I was looking for the "convenience" of having each Device entity have a "type" property which would point to a strong Objective-C object, as well as being able to use Core Data bindings for the UI to add/edit devices.  Each Device is a piece of audio gear, so I think that it will be more common than not for users to be adding them to their workspaces often.  Can a PLIST file be connected to a native object?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "connected". A PLIST file simply contains a persisted Cocoa container (NSDictionary or NSArray) that you read in (producing a dict or array). If all the managed object's attribute is storing is essentially a lookup code, you'd be translating it anyway ([deviceManager deviceInstanceForID:[myManagedObject valueForKey:@"deviceID"]]). Otherwise, use Core Data and be done with it. You can always create the list at launch if it's missing and verify/curate it on the fly.

Comment: Ahh ok I have never used a PLIST file before, that makes perfect sense.  Thank you!